# Predicting the convergence for Particle Swarm Optimization algorithm (PSO) population

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a standard PSO algorithm implementation. I want to compare the data captured from PSO with some real network. I want to test how good pso is in predicting the network.
Which brings me to the main question, how can we make prediction about working of pso. I mean which techniques can I use to achieve predictions for pso.
I want to implement in mathematica so any pseudo code will be helpful

Comment: I am going to make a guess that `PSO` has something to do with the bees. Please present a *minimal* example with enough code to replicate the challenge you face. One needs to copy/paste/study the code before offering advice.

Comment: Technically, this is an off-topic question (and will remain so) because it is requesting help with the selection of an algorithm. It is up to the OP to improve this situation.

Comment: This is really unclear if “pso” means “particle swarm optimization”. And even more unclear if it doesn’t. There is just not enough information about the problem at hand, or the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

You need a weighted positive norm on a significant subset of model output data, that can be compared to observable system data. In most cases, the square of differences, weighted with their observed variance, will do. After many runs one will change the basis so, that the different dimensions become statistically optimaliter independent.

This is not a GPT generated text.

Its based on experiences I made araound 1978, developing a random walk model of transmitter molecules to mimic the response voltage of a single photo receptor of a cows eye after absorbing a single photon.

Written in FORTRAN IV and running on a Telefunken TR440 with 256! MB memory at some 100 MHz.

The geometric and physical model variables made a random walk with step width reduced according to the differences between output and recorded data.

The problem was to reproduce  the noisy signal.

Its easy to model smooth vectors as functions of time, but to model noisy graphs is a difficult and challenging problem.  Today it constitutes the central topic of finance market simulations and analysis.

Comment: Hi Roland, could you please elaborate the approach you mentioned in the above answer about weighted positive norm. I have added the captured data for the real network in the form of a adjacency matrix. And the PSO algorithm creates one adjacency matrix.

Comment: +1 This is not a GPT generated text.

Comment: “Not a ChatGPT generated text” does not equate to “relevant”. More detail is required.

Comment: Instead of me  OCRing some 70 pages of the FORTRAN  program (1978) and the images produced on the tectronix photocopy terminal, we may  have a look the images in https://elifesciences.org/articles/67446 (2021)  and imagine the Wiener diffusion processes of some 100 Ca++ ions released and absorbed. The Wiener diffusion process in the parameter space is controlled, lets say, by the L_1 norm of differnce of experimental and simulated  curves, but noise similarity is an essential addtional  feature of so small physical systems.